# SwiftUI : Show map marker on center of map & drag to get the coordinates

Tags: xcode, swiftui, mapkit, mapkitannotation, swiftui-map

In swiftui, I want to show a map view with a marker to a specific location aligned with the map's center. when I move the map, the marker also needs to move to get the location of the specific point. I tried the below code but the map moves and the marker doesn't. is there any solution

```
struct MapView: View {
    @ObservedObject var appTheme: AppTheme
    
    struct MapMarker: Identifiable {
        let id = UUID()
        var coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D
    }
    
    @State private var markerCoordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 37.7749, longitude: -122.4194)
    @State private var mapCoordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 37.7749, longitude: -122.4194)
    @GestureState private var translation: CGSize = .zero
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Map(coordinateRegion: .constant(MKCoordinateRegion(center: mapCoordinate, span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.05, longitudeDelta: 0.05))),
                showsUserLocation: true,
                userTrackingMode: .constant(.follow),
                annotationItems: [MapMarker(coordinate: markerCoordinate)],
                annotationContent: { item in
                MapPin(coordinate: item.coordinate, tint: .red)
            })
        }
        .gesture(DragGesture()
            .updating($translation) { value, state, _ in
                state = value.translation
            }
            .onEnded { value in
                let offset = value.translation
                let translation = CGSize(width: offset.width / 1000, height: -offset.height / 1000)
                mapCoordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: mapCoordinate.latitude + translation.height, longitude: mapCoordinate.longitude + translation.width)
                markerCoordinate = mapCoordinate
                print("New Marker Coordinate: \(markerCoordinate)")
            }
        )
        .onAppear {
            print("Initial Marker Coordinate: \(markerCoordinate)")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sounds like you just want to get the coordinates of the map's centre whenever the map camera changes? You don't need to reinvent the whole drag gesture, and you don't need a map pin. Map pins moves with the map, as you have probably found out. Just put an `overlay` on top of the map if you want to indicate where the centre is.